# mysqldb auto add ' ' to %s

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Here are a piece of my python code, and the probe_id is a string :

```
sql = "select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = %s"                                                                                                                  
cursor = connection.cursor()                                     
cursor.execute(sql, (probe_id, ))
```

It works well, and but when I change the sql above to

```
sql = "select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = '%s'"
```

It gives me such error info:

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123''' at line 1")

When I add the '' surrounding the %s , It fails. But why ?

and I turn on the mysql general_log to see the sql to be executed.

```
2017-07-19T13:21:37.107960Z        85 Query     select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = '123'
```

It's my first code's sql log which works well.

but I think in the first code the final sql should be :

```
select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = 123
```

how it works?

I read the MySQLdb python code . in execute function :

```
if args is not None:
if isinstance(args, dict):
   query = query % dict((key, db.literal(item))
       for key, item in args.iteritems())
   else:
       query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
```

I think It does not do the extra work said like @money.

Comment: Why do you think that final query should be : select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = 123. probe_id is a string field then it should be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: but how to explain that it give an error if I surround the %s by quotes in sql like this sql = "select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = '%s'" ?

Comment: I think cursor.execute(sql, (probe_id,)) just escape string and  then format string using the  "select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = %s", and the %s is not surrouned by quote.

Comment: Seems when replacing the %s with the value, that is also putting extra single quotes and making your pramavalue surrounded with two single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As per the details, even without providing a single quote around the value, final query looks like
`select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = '123'`
Value already has single quotes, So when you explicitly add single quotes around the value, it make it something like
`select flow_id from t_static_flow where probe_id = ''123'' and breaks the query.`

Comment: what is the meaning of "value already has single quotes"? the string of probe_id is 123 , not including the single quotes

Answer (score 1):

I think I catched the answer. Firstly thanks @money's help.

In MySQLdb's **execute** function which I mentioned in question, it uses the **literal** function to escape the string . In fact the literal calls a C API to solve this problem. And the real escape function is [mysql_real_escape_string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html). In this document, I found this words:

> Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped.

Here are the words I found in _mysql.c

> string_literal(obj) -- converts object obj into a SQL string literal.
>   This means, any special SQL characters are escaped, and it is enclosed
>   within single quotes.

So It quotes the string in the mysql_real_esacep_string() API and return.

So In the **execute** 's code, the **query % ...** replaces the string contained the single quotes already.

same as @money said.